# Erro ao instalar aplicativo no celular

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Estou recebendo este erro ao tentar instalar no meu celular a aplicação, e nao estou conseguindo encontrar o erro dentro do manifesto.]

Estou recebendo este erro ao tentar instalar no meu celular a aplicação, e nao estou conseguindo encontrar o erro dentro do manifesto.

Comment: Não use imagens para mostrar seu código, copie o código e cole usando as ferramentas do site para melhor ajudarmos vc.

Comment: Se vc ler seu erro direito, está dizendo que tem um erro na linha 32 do XML. "<activity> não tem um android:name válido".

Comment: Só vou fazer algumas observações na estrutura do seu projeto: preferencialmente, coloque os nomes dos pacotes sempre em minúsculo (activitys). O domínio sempre é de traz para frente (br.com.aulasfirebasee.myapplication). Você pode fazer essa estrutura de pacotes (referente ao domínio) ser sua estrutura principal e colocar todas as classes dentro dele. A partir daí, vc pode criar outros pacotes e separar suas classes aí. Mais informações: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema é bastante recorrente. Isso sempre acontece quando há uma versão do app instalada no celular que difere do que estar sendo debugado e creio que, no seu caso, possa ser o nome do app. O que deve ser feito é desinstalar o app que se encontra no celular e limpar os dados do projeto no Android Studio, indo em `Menu Superio > Build > Clean Project`. Sempre funciona para mim, em último caso, reinicie o celular e o Android Studio, se não resolver, o problema deve está em seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

No windows, é necessário instalar o drive específico do seu aparelho celular para que o mesmo seja reconhecido corretamente.